How to secure mobile keyboards from key-logger attacks ? And any other way to restrict other keyboards access except google keyboard in flutter?
Have doubts about a third party keyboard able to read info from flutter mobile app [key-logger attack]. How to prevent KeyLogger attack in Fluter and How to secure mobile keyboards from key-logger attacks in flutter?
Created custom numeric keyboard but need QWERTY keyboard.
